# 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2' Error happens when trying to set an object from a VC to another one

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

Let's say I have a 2 ViewController: A and B.

Here is some code of A:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
CategoryVC *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"categoryVC"];
PParser *destPP = [[PParser alloc] init];
[destPP initWithFullURL:@"http://someurl.com"];
//setPp gives the Error EXC_BAD_ACCESS
[vc setPp:destPP];
SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController *segue = [[SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"ANY_ID" source:self destination:vc];
[segue perform];
```

Here is some code of B:

```
-(void)setPp:(PParser *)pp{
    self.pp = pp;
}
```

I guess this error has to do with the pointer which is not set correctly?Why do I get this error, and how should I fix it?

Comment: You need to declare a `property` and `synthesize` `PParser` object in destination controller instead overriding setter method.

Comment: The setter causes an infinite loop, because `self.pp =` calls itself. To avoid that you **must** set the underlying instance variable `_pp`. But if you are using ARC you don't need the explicit setter at all.

Comment: Thank you, but i've read somewhere that we don't need to use synthesize anymore since the last few versions. is it wrong?

Comment: You don't need `synthesize` and you don't need to write the setter. Just declare the property.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, i'll read more about the difference between self.var and _var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void)setPp:(PParser *)pp  
{
  _pp = pp;
}
```

Comment: self.pp = pp is same as calling [self setPp:pp], it's recursive invocation.